# knockoutjs - making a quiz

Tags: json, html, knockout.js

knockoutjs file:

```
    $(function () {
    $('#info').hide();
    QuizViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(new QuizViewModel());

    $('#restart').click(function () {
        location.reload();
    });
    });


    function QuizViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.previous = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.questions = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.current = ko.observable();
        self.number = ko.observable(0);
        self.previousNumbers = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.selectedAnswers = ko.observableArray();
        self.correctAnswers = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.loadQuestions = function () {
            $('#questionsAndAnswers').fadeOut('fast');
            $.getJSON('./json/quiz.json', function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, q) {
                    self.questions.push(q);
                    if (q.answers.tf == "true") {
                        self.correctAnswers.push(q.answers.question);
                    }
                    else {
                    //
                    }

                });
            });
            $('#questions').fadeIn('fast');

        }
        self.getQuestion = function (number) {
            $.getJSON('./json/quiz.json', function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, q) {
                    if (number == i) {
                        self.current(q);
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        self.nextQuestion = function (selectedAnswer) {
            if (self.previousNumbers().length == 15) {
                $('#questionsAndAnswers').fadeIn('fast');
                $('#questions').fadeOut('fast');
            } else {

                var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)

                if (self.previousNumbers.indexOf(random) == -1) {
                    if (self.previousNumbers().length > 0) {
                        self.current().selectedAnswers = self.selectedAnswers();
                        //alert(self.current().selectedAnswers[0] + " " + self.current().selectedAnswers[1]);
                        if ($.inArray(self.current().selectedAnswers[0], this.correctAnswers) > -1) {
                            $('#infoCorrect').show();
                        }
                        self.previous.push(self.current());
                        self.selectedAnswers.removeAll();
                    }
                    self.previousNumbers.push(random);
                    self.getQuestion(random);
                    var previousNumber = self.number();
                    self.number(previousNumber + 1);

                } else {
                    self.nextQuestion();
                }


            }

        }

        $('#questionsAndAnswers').fadeOut('fast');

        self.nextQuestion();

    }
```

first part of my json file: tf = true or false (just to give it a name)

```
    [ 
    {"id" : 1,
    "question": "Welke stad is de hoofdstad van Brazili\u00eb?", 
    "answers" : [{"answer":"Rio de Janeiro", "tf":"false"}, 
            {"answer":"Brasilia", "tf":"true"}, 
            {"answer":"Sa\u00F5 Paulo", "tf":"false"}],
    "info" : "De hoofdstad van Brazili\u00eb is Brasilia en niet Rio de Janeiro of Sa\u00F5     Paulo zoals de meesten denken. Tot 1960 was Rio de Janeiro inderdaad de hoofdstad, maar     vanaf dan nam de nieuwe stad Brasilia deze functie over. Niettemin zijn Rio de Janeiro en     Sa\u00F5 Paulo zeer belangrijke steden voor het land met respectievelijk 11 en 6 miljoen     inwoners."
    },  ...
```

html5 page:

```
    <div id ="questions" data-bind="with: current">

        <h1 id="title">Quiz rond het thema: Brazili&euml; - Sisal</h1>
                    <p class="question" data-bind="text: question"></p>
                    <div  class="answers" data-bind="foreach: answers">
                        <p data-bind="with: $data">
                            <input id="checkboxes"type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.selectedAnswers, value: answer"/>
                            <span class="answer" data-bind="text: answer"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <p id="info" class = "answers" data-bind="text: info"></p>
                    <img id="img1" class="buttons" src="img/next.png" title="Volgende vraag" data-bind="click: $root.nextQuestion"/>
                </div>
</section>
                <div id ="questionsAndAnswers">
                    <div>
                        <div  data-bind="foreach: previous">
                            <p class="question" data-bind="text: question"></p>
                            <div data-bind="foreach: selectedAnswers">
                                <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div data-bind="foreach: answers">
                                <p data-bind="with: $data">
                                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: answer, checked: tf=='true'" disabled="true"/>
                                    <span class="answer" data-bind="text: answer"> </span><span data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedAnswers"></span>
    </p>
    </div>
    <div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img id="restart" class="buttons" src="img/start.png" title="Herstart de quiz" />
                </div>
```

Can someone tell me how to check the selected answer with the correct answer in the json file.. And then show the p tag with id="info" ?

i'm using an array now to check this (correctAnswers)

Comment: Could you post a fiddle of your question? It would make answering this a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified your code for my needs. Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/wJhqB/

Summary :

```
 // In every getQuestion function empty correctAnswers array
 self.correctAnswers.remove(function(item){return true;});
 // Create correct answer array for current question
 $.each(q.answers , function(j,a) {                    
         if (a.tf == "true") {
               self.correctAnswers.push(a.answer);                 
          }
          else {                   
           }
 });
```

I used knockout mapping plugin for displaying results and simulating ajax events :

```
<p id="info" class = "answers" data-bind="text:ko.mapping.toJS($root.correctAnswers)"></p>
```

Mapping plugin Doc : http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html
Mapping plugin Source : https://raw.github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.js